# Laravel 5.2 to be logged in as a master account and an admin

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, session-cookies

I have Super Admin and Store Admins login. That I had achieved with `entrust` Package.

Now, in the Super Admin side, under the listings of all the Store Admins, I want to provide a button

> go to **Dashboard**

(i.e. Super Admin Can view, login into Store Admin Dashboard with just a click with the condition that Super Admin login (session) must remain and new tab will be opened with the Store Admin Dashboard.

I got laravel function

```
\Auth::loginUsingId($store_admin_id);
```

But this close current session of Super Admin and then That admin is loggedin. I want to maintain both sessions.

On searching I found one package [olieread/multiauth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth), where I need exact solution but its for the Laravel 4.2 version.

I have session settings as default. As of now I'm not using memcache or redis. If using anyone of them can help me?

Any help suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can do simply by adding additional columns to `users` table. for more advance usage. you can easily use Laravel ACL https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-acl-package

Comment: which additional columns? I had already implement ACL, now I want super admin to view dashboard of subadmins.